# Errores en Nginx (2: No such file or directory)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

No se en qué momento, nginx dejó de funcionar.
Estoy ejecutando nginx en elementary os 6.1 (fork de ubuntu 20.04)

Al ejecutar sudo nginx -t obtengo estos errores:

`nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`

`2022/03/12 22:13:51 [emerg] 37113#37113: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

`nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`

Estuve buscando bastante y no encuentro solución :( . En la gran mayoría de las páginas aparece esta (https://gist.github.com/plencovich/e38e7a3d2ff977089fc4e06be1e738ed) pero no funciona...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

los logs se crean automáticamente (tanto el de errores como el de acceso), pero si se han configurado para ir a un directorio que no existe, no tienen permiso para crearlo recursivamente. Por una única vez tendrás que crearlo tú

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/nginx
```

asegúrate de asignar como grupo `adm`, con lo cual el usuario `syslog` y otros loggers pueden funcionar sin que tengas que relajar los permisos.

```
sudo chown root:adm /var/log/nginx
```